# MySQL Regex - How to look for a specific sequential set of words

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm trying to query my MySQL database using this regex string,

```
^(?=.*?\\bAuto\\b)(?=.*?\\bAnd\\b)(?=.*?\\bFashion\\b)(?=.*?\\bFair\\b).*$
```

on my localhost it works perfectly but on the remote server I get an error as follows:

```
[03-Mar-2017 09:49:47 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1139 Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp' in /home/public_html/assets/sys/pdo.php:491
```

FYI, The query string generated is as follows:

```
$SELECT * FROM table WHERE name REGEXP "^(?=.*?\\bAuto\\b)(?=.*?\\bAnd\\b)(?=.*?\\bFashion\\b)(?=.*?\\bFair\\b).*$" AND status = 1
```

Comment: Split into several `WHERE name REGEXP "[[:<:]]Auto[[:>:]]" AND WHERE name REGEXP "[[:<:]]And[[:>:]]" AND WHERE name REGEXP "[[:<:]]Fashion[[:>:]]" AND WHERE name REGEXP "[[:<:]]Fair[[:>:]]"`. `\b` is not supported by MySQL regex and lookarounds are not supported either.

Comment: MySQL's `REGEXP` does not  handle `(?`; MariaDB's does.

Answer (score 0):

[MySQL regex](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) is POSIX based, and does not support the following in your regex pattern:

- `(?=...)` - lookarounds (neither lookaheads, nor lookbehinds)
- `*?` - lazy quantifiers
- `\\b` - word boundary is written as `[[:<:]]` (start of the word position) and `[[:>:]]` (end of the word position).

As the `^(?=.*?\\bAuto\\b)(?=.*?\\bAnd\\b)(?=.*?\\bFashion\\b)(?=.*?\\bFair\\b).*$` regex matches *any string* that has all the whole words listed inside the positive lookaheads, you can only re-write your current regex as a series of `WHERE name REGEXP "<whole_word>"`:

```
WHERE name REGEXP "[[:<:]]Auto[[:>:]]" AND WHERE name REGEXP "[[:<:]]And[[:>:]]" AND WHERE name REGEXP "[[:<:]]Fashion[[:>:]]" AND WHERE name REGEXP "[[:<:]]Fair[[:>:]]"
```

Also, if you need a case sensitive search, you need to use `BINARY` after `REGEXP`.